# Properties of entire functions of which the $n$-derivatives have uncountably many zeros

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function and $$A = \{z \in \mathbb C: f^{(n)} (z) = 0 \text{ for some positive integer } n\}.$$
Then what can we say about the function $f$ if $A$ is uncountable?

Answer (score 2):

The zeroes of an analytic function are isolated;  and any uncountable subset of the plane has an accumulation point. So, there is some $n $ with $f^{(n)}=0$, and thus $f $ is a polynomial of degree  $n-1$ or less.

Comment: And the union of countably many countable sets is countable, so if the union over $n$ is uncountable, then it is uncountable for some fixed $n$.

Comment: Thanks. I clarified the writing just a bit, but I still want to leave some work for the OP to do.

Comment: please elaborate OP?